# vbScript Arrat Error

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I have below CoreAPP.txt log file:

> [10/31/2012 19:53:41:889 SWAP INF] {hap=CB2:app=Internet Explorer_b1
>   6.0.3790.3959:tid=22C0:usr=B9D327} Elapsed time for upload: 0.718 seconds
>
> [10/31/2012 19:53:42:639 SWAP INF] {hap=CB2:app=Internet Explorer_b1
>   6.0.3790.3959:tid=22C0:usr=V9V327} Elapsed time for launch: 3.250 seconds
>
> [10/31/2012 19:56:37:815 ???? INF] {tid=4004:usr=V47235} An error
>   occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc:
>   07B01F0C-0000004A
>
> [10/31/2012 19:56:37:846 ???? INF] {tid=4004} An error occurred while
>   opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A
>
> [10/31/2012 10:45:00:576 ???? INF] {tid=1650} An error occurred while
>   opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A ElapR
>   The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL
>   'RTSP://SRVW23E:554/V1321_BDP_V1_R1_SB/V1321_BDP_C1_P2PM_SS.sft' (rc
>   1690900A-00002002, original rc 1690900A-00002002).
>
> [10/31/2012 00:29:59:843 OSDF ERR] {tid=1464} The Application
>   Virtualization Client could not parse the OSD file
>   'C:\SoftCache\SoftGrid Client\OSD
>   Cache\edCc4305-3f6C-4dcc-3d70-404eb8bd97d8.osd'. Reason: XML parsing
>   failure (rc 00000A25-00000002)
>
> [10/31/2012 08:24:35:869 ???? ERR] {tid=336C:usr=t405230} corrupt cp
>   file detected ('V:\V1321_BDP\osguard.cp'). osguard cp file, NO
>   CORRECTIVE ACTION TAKEN
>
> [10/31/2012 22:16:39:240 JGSW ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS
>   1.0:tid=3D58} The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL
>   'RTSP://PSWQAPP1:554/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS.sft'
>   (rc 1690900A-00002002, original rc 1690900A-00002002).
>
> [10/31/2012 22:16:39:240 SWAP ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS
>   1.0:tid=3D58} The client was unable to connect to an Application Virtualization Server (rc 1690900A-00002002)
>
> [10/31/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54} The specified
>   application name (Application Integration) is ambiguous. Some
>   potential matches: Application Integration 7.0.1756.1756 Application
>   Integration 9.2.2373.2373
>
> [10/31/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54} The Application
>   Virtualization Client cannot open Application Integration
>
> [10/31/2012 00:03:14:313 SWAP WRN] {tid=507C:usr=N28712} Could not
>   load OSD file
>   \PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader
>   9.3.3.osd
>
> [10/31/2012 00:03:14:313 AMGR INF] {tid=507C:usr=i435145} The app
>   manager could not create an application from
>   '\PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adob_dobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe
>   Reader 9.3.3.osd' (rc 0C405664-00000002).
>
> ==== [10/31/2012 13:35:16:987 JGSW ERR] {hap=1:app=Abaculus 1.0.0.1:tid=14C8:usr=R3R7DF42} The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL
>   'RTSP:%SFT_SRV%:554/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01.sft'
>   (rc 19D02E0A-10000002, original rc 19D02E0A-10000002).
>
> [10/31/2012 13:35:47:998 SWAP ERR] {hap=2:app=AboutPI-SDK
>   1.3.0.26:tid=1568:usr=I337721} Could not load app
>
> [10/31/2012 19:56:37:862 SWAP INF] {hap=CB3:app=Adobe Reader X
>   10.0.1.434:tid=4004:usr=V47235} Elapsed time for upload: 0.609 seconds
>
> [10/31/2012 19:56:38:393 SWAP INF] {hap=CB3:app=Adobe Reader X
>   10.0.1.434:tid=4004:usr=V47236} Elapsed time for launch: 1.187 seconds
>
> [10/31/2012 19:56:57:487 SWAP INF] {hap=CB3:app=Adobe Reader X
>   10.0.1.434:tid=4004:usr=V47234} App shut down
>
> [10/31/2012 20:01:40:745 ???? INF] {tid=327C:usr=V42235} An error
>   occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc:
>   07B01F0C-0000004A
>
> [10/31/2012 20:01:40:776 ???? INF] {tid=327C} An error occurred while
>   opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A
>
> [10/31/2012 20:01:40:776 SWAP INF] {hap=CB4:app=Adobe Reader X
>   10.0.1.434:tid=327C:usr=V422357235} Elapsed time for upload: 0.609 seconds
>
> [11/01/2012 16:48:44:157 SWAP INF] {hap=11A4:app=Lotus Notes_b1
>   6.5.40.5086:tid=361C:usr=A422353001} Elapsed time for launch: 5.219 seconds
>
> [11/01/2012 16:50:21:003 ???? INF] {tid=32D8:usr=W8WS83} An error
>   occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc:
>   07B01F0C-0000004A
>
> [11/01/2012 16:50:21:066 ???? INF] {tid=32D8} An error occurred while
>   opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A
>
> [11/01/2012 16:50:21:082 SWAP INF] {hap=11A5:app=Adobe Reader X
>   10.0.1.434:tid=32D8:usr=W8WS83} Elapsed time for upload: 0.703 seconds
>
> [11/01/2012 16:50:22:503 SWAP INF] {hap=11A5:app=Adobe Reader X
>   10.0.1.434:tid=32D8:usr=W8WS83} Elapsed time for launch: 2.218 seconds
>
> [11/01/2012 16:50:50:395 SWAP INF] {hap=11A5:app=Adobe Reader X
>   10.0.1.434:tid=32D8:usr=A422353001} App shut down
>
> [11/01/2012 16:53:24:367 ???? INF] {tid=1F80:usr=t405230} An error
>   occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc:
>   07B01F0C-0000004A
>
> [11/01/2012 16:53:24:383 ???? INF] {tid=1F80} An error occurred while
>   opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A
>
> [11/01/2012 16:53:24:383 SWAP INF] {hap=11A6:app=Show Desktop
>   1.0:tid=1F80:usr=A422353001} Elapsed time for upload: 0.531 seconds
>
> [11/01/2012 16:53:24:727 SWAP INF] {hap=11A7:app=Microsoft Office
>   Excel 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=251C:usr=V422357235} Elapsed time for
>   upload: 0.0 seconds
>
> [11/01/2012 16:53:24:758 SWAP INF] {hap=11A6:app=Show Desktop
>   1.0:tid=1F80:usr=V47234} Elapsed time for launch: 1.78 seconds
>
> [11/01/2012 16:53:25:117 SWAP INF] {hap=11A6:app=Show Desktop
>   1.0:tid=1F80:usr=V422357235} App shut down
>
> [11/01/2012 10:45:00:576 ???? INF] {tid=1650} An error occurred while
>   opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A ElapR
>   The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL
>   'RTSP://SRVW23E:554/V1321_BDP_V1_R1_SB/V1321_BDP_C1_P2PM_SS.sft' (rc
>   1690900A-00002002, original rc 1690900A-00002002).
>
> [11/01/2012 00:29:59:843 OSDF ERR] {tid=1464} The Application
>   Virtualization Client could not parse the OSD file
>   'C:\SoftCache\SoftGrid Client\OSD
>   Cache\edCc4305-3f6C-4dcc-3d70-404eb8bd97d8.osd'. Reason: XML parsing
>   failure (rc 00000A25-00000002)
>
> [11/01/2012 08:24:35:869 ???? ERR] {tid=336C:usr=t405230} corrupt cp
>   file detected ('V:\V1321_BDP\osguard.cp'). osguard cp file, NO
>   CORRECTIVE ACTION TAKEN
>
> [11/01/2012 22:16:39:240 JGSW ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS
>   1.0:tid=3D58} The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL
>   'RTSP://PSWQAPP1:554/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS.sft'
>   (rc 1690900A-00002002, original rc 1690900A-00002002).
>
> [11/01/2012 22:16:39:240 SWAP ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS
>   1.0:tid=3D58} The client was unable to connect to an Application Virtualization Server (rc 1690900A-00002002)
>
> [11/01/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54} The specified
>   application name (Application Integration) is ambiguous. Some
>   potential matches: Application Integration 7.0.1756.1756 Application
>   Integration 9.2.2373.2373
>
> [11/01/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54} The Application
>   Virtualization Client cannot open Application Integration
>
> [11/01/2012 00:03:14:313 SWAP WRN] {tid=507C:usr=N28712} Could not
>   load OSD file
>   \PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader
>   9.3.3.osd
>
> [11/01/2012 00:03:14:313 AMGR INF] {tid=507C:usr=i435145} The app
>   manager could not create an application from
>   '\PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adob_dobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe
>   Reader 9.3.3.osd' (rc 0C405664-00000002).
>
> ====
>
> [11/01/2012 13:35:16:987 JGSW ERR] {hap=1:app=Abaculus
>   1.0.0.1:tid=14C8:usr=R3R7DF42} The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL
>   'RTSP:%SFT_SRV%:554/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01.sft'
>   (rc 19D02E0A-10000002, original rc 19D02E0A-10000002).
>
> [11/01/2012 13:35:47:998 SWAP ERR] {hap=2:app=AboutPI-SDK
>   1.3.0.26:tid=1568:usr=I337721} Could not load app [11/01/2012 16:53:25:399 SWAP INF] {hap=11A7:app=Microsoft Office Excel 2003_b1
>   11.0.8324.1:tid=251C:usr=V47234} Elapsed time for launch: 0.891 seconds
>
> [11/05/2012 10:43:37:527 SWAP INF] {hap=1510:app=Adobe Reader X
>   10.0.1.434:tid=2AE8:usr=V47234} App shut down
>
> [11/05/2012 10:44:00:793 SWAP INF] {hap=1511:app=Microsoft Office Word
>   2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=1D80:usr=V422357235} Elapsed time for upload:
>   0.0 seconds
>
> [11/05/2012 10:44:03:809 SWAP INF] {hap=1511:app=Microsoft Office Word
>   2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=1D80:usr=V422357235} Elapsed time for launch:
>   3.172 seconds
>
> [11/05/2012 10:44:15:965 SWAP INF] {hap=1511:app=Microsoft Office Word
>   2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=1D80:usr=V422357235} App shut down
>
> [11/05/2012 10:44:20:637 SWAP INF] {hap=1512:app=Microsoft Office Word
>   2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=3B9C:usr=V47234} Elapsed time for upload: 0.0
>   seconds
>
> [11/05/2012 10:44:23:606 SWAP INF] {hap=1512:app=Microsoft Office Word
>   2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=3B9C:usr=V47234} Elapsed time for launch:
>   3.125 seconds
>
> [11/05/2012 10:44:32:481 SWAP INF] {hap=150B:app=Microsoft Office
>   Excel 2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=19C:usr=V47234} App shut down
>
> [11/05/2012 10:44:38:575 SWAP INF] {hap=1512:app=Microsoft Office Word
>   2003_b1 11.0.8324.1:tid=3B9C:usr=E831415} App shut down
>
> [11/05/2012 10:45:00:560 ???? INF] {tid=1650:usr=V47234} An error
>   occurred while opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc:
>   07B01F0C-0000004A
>
> [11/05/2012 10:45:00:576 ???? INF] {tid=1650} An error occurred while
>   opening the virtual registry (section: 9), rc: 07B01F0C-0000004A ElapR
>   The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL
>   'RTSP://SRVW23E:554/V1321_BDP_V1_R1_SB/V1321_BDP_C1_P2PM_SS.sft' (rc
>   1690900A-00002002, original rc 1690900A-00002002).
>
> [11/05/2012 00:29:59:843 OSDF ERR] {tid=1464} The Application
>   Virtualization Client could not parse the OSD file
>   'C:\SoftCache\SoftGrid Client\OSD
>   Cache\edCc4305-3f6C-4dcc-3d70-404eb8bd97d8.osd'. Reason: XML parsing
>   failure (rc 00000A25-00000002)
>
> [11/05/2012 08:24:35:869 ???? ERR] {tid=336C:usr=t405230} corrupt cp
>   file detected ('V:\V1321_BDP\osguard.cp'). osguard cp file, NO
>   CORRECTIVE ACTION TAKEN
>
> [11/05/2012 22:16:39:240 JGSW ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS
>   1.0:tid=3D58} The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL
>   'RTSP://PSWQAPP1:554/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS/V14678993_BDP_C15_E2AM_SS.sft'
>   (rc 1690900A-00002002, original rc 1690900A-00002002).
>
> [11/05/2012 22:16:39:240 SWAP ERR] {hap=1C82:app=bDP c15 E2AM SS
>   1.0:tid=3D58} The client was unable to connect to an Application Virtualization Server (rc 1690900A-00002002)
>
> [11/05/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54} The specified
>   application name (Application Integration) is ambiguous. Some
>   potential matches: Application Integration 7.0.1756.1756 Application
>   Integration 9.2.2373.2373
>
> [11/05/2012 22:17:09:163 AMGR ERR] {tid=4F54} The Application
>   Virtualization Client cannot open Application Integration
>
> [11/05/2012 00:03:14:313 SWAP WRN] {tid=507C:usr=N28712} Could not
>   load OSD file
>   \PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adobe_Reader
>   9.3.3.osd
>
> [11/05/2012 00:03:14:313 AMGR INF] {tid=507C:usr=i435145} The app
>   manager could not create an application from
>   '\PSWQAPP1\Content\D1311_bDP_Adob_dobe_Reader_9.3.3\D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe
>   Reader 9.3.3.osd' (rc 0C405664-00000002).
>
> ==== [11/05/2012 13:35:16:987 JGSW ERR] {hap=1:app=Abaculus 1.0.0.1:tid=14C8:usr=R3R7DF42} The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream URL
>   'RTSP:%SFT_SRV%:554/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01/D1311_bDP_Adob_b_Adobe_Abaculus_15_01.sft'
>   (rc 19D02E0A-10000002, original rc 19D02E0A-10000002).
>
> [11/05/2012 13:35:47:998 SWAP ERR] {hap=2:app=AboutPI-SDK
>   1.3.0.26:tid=1568:usr=I337721} Could not load app

My script always read the above log from current date... and catch the array of errors...

```
option Explicit

const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

dim arrErrors(5)
dim objFSO, objServerList, objErrorLog, strErrorLine, strError
dim strComputer, strToday, strFilePath, objCoreApp, strLine, today, i 

set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objServerList = objFSO.OpenTextFile("list.txt", ForReading, false, TriStateTrue)
set objErrorLog = objFSO.CreateTextFile("error.log")

strToday = Date()

arrErrors(0) = "The Application Virtualization Client could not connect to stream"
arrErrors(1) = "XML parsing failure"
arrErrors(2) = "corrupt cp file detected"
arrErrors(3) = "The client was unable to connect"
arrErrors(4) = "Virtualization Client cannot open Application Integration"
arrErrors(5) = "Could not load OSD file"

Do while not (objServerList.AtEndOfStream)
  strComputer = objServerList.ReadLine

  strFilePath = "\\" & strComputer & "\d$\LOGFILES\"

  set objCoreApp = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath & "CoreAPP.txt", ForReading, False, TriStateTrue)

  objErrorLog.WriteLine strComputer & vbTab & "," & vbTab & "Checking"

  do while not (objCoreApp.AtEndOfStream)
    strLine = objCoreApp.ReadLine

    'If InStr (strLine, today) = 0 Then

    if (left(strLine, len(strToday) + 1) = "[" & strToday) then
      strErrorLine = objCoreApp.ReadLine

      for i = 0 to ubound(arrErrors)
        strError = arrErrors(i)

        if (left(lcase(strErrorLine), len(strError)) = lcase(strError)) then
          objErrorLog.WriteLine strErrorLine & vbTab & strComputer
          exit for
        end If
      next
    end If
  loop
  objCoreApp.close
loop
objErrorLog.WriteLine "Completed Checking all the servers"

objErrorLog.Close
objServerList.Close
MsgBox "Script Completed"
```

The Problem with the above script is.. Script able to catch only "corrupt cp file detected"...only... In-fact the above all array cases are true but not catching and writing in the log file... not sure why it is not catching the remaining errors...
looking for help...

When I compile above script with above log file... got below output...

```
MYserver1   ,   Checking
corrupt cp file detected adsa   MYserver1   
Completed Checking all the servers
```

Comment: Your code expects the error message to be in the line *after* the line with the date. Is that correct? Or is the error message in the same line as the date in the log file? The log snippet you posted seems to be mangled. Please update the snippet in your question so that it has the same line breaks as the original log file, or post the snippet to a [pastebin](http://www.pylonsproject.org/tools/pastebins).

Comment: The error can be after the Current Date...

The above log is collected from actual log file and copy pasted above..

looking for help in this.....

Thanks in advance

Comment: The lines in the log snippet in your question are re-formatted and thus useless. Please post an unmodified log snippet to a pastebin (see link in my previous comment) and post that link back here.